# how do add to a key value to javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JS.  It seems simple but I am not sure how to do this.

having this javascript object based on this good 
[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688097/objects-vs-arrays-in-javascript-for-key-value-pairs)

```
var people = {
  1: { name: 'Joe' },
  2: { name: 'Sam' },
  3: { name: 'Eve' }
};
```

How do I add the following value

```
4: { name: 'John' }
```

To get name Eve I write

```
 people["1"].name
```

Comment: This is the JSON notation: http://json.org/

Comment: In the original thread, the keys were sparse (1, 3, 8) not consecutive (1,2,3), so I don't know if all the suggestions to switch to an array fit what the questioner wants to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assign the anonymous object to it the way you would any other value.

```
people["4"] = { name: 'John' };
```

For what it's worth, since your keys are numeric you could also use zero-based indices and make people an array.

```
var people = [ { name: 'Joe' },
               { name: 'Sam' },
               { name: 'Eve' } ];
```

and

```
alert( people[2].name ); // outputs Eve
people[3] = { name: 'John' };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think people should be an array :

```
var people = [
  { name: 'Joe' },
  { name: 'Sam' },
  { name: 'Eve' }
];
```

as the keys are integers, so you can add a person by :

```
people.push({name:'John'});
```

You can acces to the people by doing :

```
var somebody = people[1]; /// >>> Sam
```