# How to append a new item to same index in same array inside the for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have obj of array

```
var data = [{
    value: 1,
    t: 1487203500000
}, {
    value: 2,
    t: 1487213700000
}];
```

here, i need to compare t obj at inside a loop, if it is exceeds 5 mins, then i need to create a one item with value of null and append into that array.

Expected result will be

```
var data = [{
    value: 1,
    t: 1487203500000
}, {
    value: null,
    t: null
} {
    value: 2,
    t: 1487213700000
}];
```

while appending i need to push into same index and existing value should be readjusted.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917904/how-do-add-to-a-key-value-to-javascript-object

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object

Comment: What exactly *if it is exceeds 5 mins* means for you? What do you want to compare your  `data[0]["t"]` to? Because obviously all of them exceed 5minutes (by years). Do you want to compare one item to the next, like `data[1]["t"] - data[0]["t"] > 5 * 60 * 1000`, and if so, insert the `null` object between them, so `data[1]` becomes `data[2]`?

Comment: @wscourge, yes same expectation only, it should change from data[1] to data[2] nd comparing by t

Comment: I dont understand your comment since *nd comparing by t*. Could you please explain what exactly does *if it is exceeds 5 mins* mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.splice()` for this

> The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array.

```js
var data = [{
    value: 1,
    t: 1487203500000
}, {
    value: 2,
    t: 1487213700000
}];

//  put your index here
//          v
data.splice(1, 0, {value: null, t: null});

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, 0, 8));
```

In this code

```
data.splice(1, 0, {value: null, t: null});
```

> 1st Parameter (1) -> indicates the position where you want to insert.
>   2nd Parameter (0) -> indicates how many elements you want to remove.
>   3rd Parameter ({obj}) -> is the object which we want to insert at position 1.