# How to access an element in an array, within an array, within another array...in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to call an element in an array, that is in another array, that is in yet another array. 
for example....

```
  var a1 = ["1","2","3"];
  var a2 = ["4","5","6"];
  var a3 = ["7","8","9"];
  var a4 = ["10","11","12"];

  var b1 = ["a1","a2"];
  var b2 = ["a3","a4"];

  var c = ["b1","b2"];

  var x = c[0];

  console.log(x);
```

The answer is `x = b1`

How can I define the `var x = c[0] b1[1] a2[2]` so that the answer would be 6?

Comment: Well, why don't you define them as nested arrays?

Comment: What is your reason for doing this?

Comment: if you want a1 to be an element of b1, don't put a1 in quotes

Comment: I trying to learn the best way to do something like this. I haven't had a lot of experience with arrays.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688097/objects-vs-arrays-in-javascript-for-key-value-pairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want are nested arrays.

```
var a1 = ["1","2","3"];
var a2 = ["4","5","6"];
var a3 = ["7","8","9"];
var a4 = ["10","11","12"];

var b1 = [a1,a2];
var b2 = [a3,a4];

var c = [b1,b2];

var x = c[0][1][2];

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

define the arrays as elements of the other arrays, rather than strings:

```
var a1 = [1, 2, 3];
...
var b1 = [a1, a2];
...
var c = [b1, b2];

var x = c[0][0][0]; // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The array `a1` isn't actually in `b1` — there's just a string containing the text "a1". If you defined them like so:

```
var a1 = ["1","2","3"];
var a2 = ["4","5","6"];
var a3 = ["7","8","9"];
var a4 = ["10","11","12"];

var b1 = [a1, a2];
var b2 = [a3, a4];

var c = [b1, b2];
```

Then you could get "6" by writing `c[0][1][2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a1 = ["1","2","3"], a2 = ["4","5","6"], a3 = ["7","8","9"], a4 = ["10","11","12"];
var b1 = [a1,a2];
var b2 = [a3,a4];
var c = [b1,b2];

var x1 = c[0][0][0];
var x2 = c[0][0][1];
var x3 = c[0][0][2];

console.log(x1); //1 (1st/0 item of a1) from c
console.log(x2); //2 (2nd/1 item of a1) from c
console.log(x3); //3 (3rd/2 item of a1) from c
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/acaruw/1/edit).