# jQuery, 'undefined' length of array of arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array structure:

```
mdarray = {
  '0001':{address:'add1',title:'title1'},
  '0002':{address:'add2',title:'title2'},
  '0003':{address:'add3',title:'title3'}
};
```

I wish to only work with the array if it has one or more items in it. Usually with an array I would use `if (mdarray.length > 0) {}` but when I do this with the array above, `mdarray.length` returns 'undefined'.

Is this is because it is an array of arrays? Is there another way to very simply pull back the number if items in the root of the array?

Or it is because the keys are strings and not integers?

I've played about with different array structures and read about multidimensional arrays but I've not yet found an answer.

Comment: no this is because this is not an array at all. This is called an object literal

Comment: That isn't an array structure, that is an Object structure, and objects don't have length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified code: you are creating Object instead of Array you should use following code: [see this thrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688097/objects-vs-arrays-in-javascript-for-key-value-pairs)

```
mdarray = [
  {address:'add1',title:'title1'},
  {address:'add2',title:'title2'},
  {address:'add3',title:'title3'}
];
```

mdarray.length // 3

Comment: Note that it is not a multi-dimensional array. It is an array of objects.

Comment: @Sushil Ah ok thanks. I think I understand the differences now, thanks for the thread link also.

Answer (score 2):

That is an Object, not an Array. So it has no length!