# How can I update a row in a javascript array based on a key value?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of data like this:

```
var nameInfo  = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
```

If I have an object like this:

```
var nameInfo  = {name: "Moroni", age: 51};
```

Is there a simple way that I can update the variable nameInfo. The key
between these is the name column. I know there is a way that I could 
do this by searching for the row, removing and adding but I would like
to have a way to do this where I updated the row. Note that if it helps I do have underscore.js loaded.

Comment: So the names are unique? Then why aren’t they the _names_ for your object properties in the first place?

Comment: Yeah I am sorry I should have mentioned. The names are unique.

Comment: Well then I’d build the whole thing up in the form `{"Moroni":{"age":51}}` – so you can check for existence of an entry by name without having to loop over all entries.

Comment: Book of Mormon names, that's cool!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update array value javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069654/how-to-update-array-value-javascript)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Easiest way is to just loop over and find the one with a matching name then update the age:

```
var newNameInfo  = {name: "Moroni", age: 51};
var name = newNameInfo.name;

for (var i = 0, l = nameInfo.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (nameInfo[i].name === name) {
        nameInfo[i].age = newNameInfo.age;
        break;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aQfk6/1/)

Using underscore you can use the [_.find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) method to do the following instead of the for loop:

```
var match = _.find(nameInfo, function(item) { return item.name === name })
if (match) {
    match.age = newNameInfo.age;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aQfk6/)

Comment: In the underscore example, i see you declared a new variable called "match" in which you have saved the outcome of _.find. Now you updated that "match" variable with the updated data. How does the original array which is "nameInfo" got updated. I am little new to underscore.

Comment: @Achyut  The variable match is a reference to the relevant item in the original array, not a copy. So updates to this are also updates to the original item.

Answer (score 12):

**Edit:** 
You can use ES6 **filter** combined with arrow functions

```
nameInfo.filter(x => {return x.name === nametofind })[0].age = newage
```

You can use  `_.where` function

```
var match = _.where(nameInfo , {name  :nametofind });
```

then update the match

```
match[0].age = newage
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var nameInfo  = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},{name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}
                ];
_.map(nameInfo, function(obj){
  if(obj.name=='Moroni') {
    obj.age=51; // Or replace the whole obj
  }
});
```

This should do it. It's neat and reliable and with underscore

Comment: Don't you need to return `obj` in the transformation function? Otherwise you'll get an array of undefined elements.

Answer (score 4):

Using Underscore you can use _.findWhere http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

```
_.findWhere(publicServicePulitzers, {newsroom: "The New York Times"});
=> {year: 1918, newsroom: "The New York Times",
  reason: "For its public service in publishing in full so many official reports,
  documents and speeches by European statesmen relating to the progress and
  conduct of the war."}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use findWhere and extend

```
obj = _.findWhere(@songs, {id: id})
_.extend(obj, {name:'foo', age:12});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the _.find method, like this:

```
var nameInfos  = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
var nameToSearch = "Moroni";
var myRecord = _.find(nameInfos, function(record){ return record.name === nameToSearch; });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9C2u3/

Comment: What if value is not present ! wont his return `undefined` ? I feel this isnt h best way to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var match = _.findWhere(nameInfo , {name  :nametofind });
match.age = newage
```

Comment: ` _.findWhere` would not be sufficient in this senario as it matches all key value pairs

Answer (score 1):

A staright forward using lodash's [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find) function,

```
var nameInfo  = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
             {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
             {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
             {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
             {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

var objToUpdate = _.find(nameInfo, {name: "Moroni"});

if(objToUpdate) objToUpdate.age = 51;

console.log(nameInfo); // Moroni age will be 51;
```

Note: If there are multiple Moroni objects, _.find can fetch the first match only.