# Javascript Update object of array by attribute of the object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of person objects and I want to update one of object in place.

```
persons: [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
    }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 13
    }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'David',
    age: 14
}]
```

The function I have is:

```
function updatePersonsWith(id, propName, value) {
   this.persons.???
}
```

The arguments passed are `id` of the person I want to update, `propName` is the properties of `person` object, can be `id`, `name` or `age`, `value` is the value I want to replace with.

I want to find an object by it's id and update only this object of the array.

```
updatePersonsWith(2, age, 16)
```

The result would be:

```
persons: [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
    }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 16
    }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'David',
    age: 14
}]
```

Could be ES6 or using lodash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update a row in a javascript array based on a key value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148150/how-can-i-update-a-row-in-a-javascript-array-based-on-a-key-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
let person = this.persons.find((person) => {
   return person.id === id;
});

if (person && person[propName]) {
 person[propName] = value;
}
```

Working example:

```js
var persons = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
    }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 13
    }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'David',
    age: 14
}];

function update(id, prop, val) {
 var person = persons.find(function(p) {
   return p.id === id;
  });
  
  if (person && person[prop]) {
   person[prop] = val;
  }
}

update('1', 'age', 77);

console.log(persons[0].age);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```js
let persons =  [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    age: 12
    }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 13
    }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'David',
    age: 14
}];


function updatePersonsWith(id, propName, value) {
   let item = persons.find((v) => {
      return v.id == id;
   });
   if (item && item.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
      item[propName] = value;
   }
};

updatePersonsWith(2, 'age', 16);
console.log(persons)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lodash`, you can do like,

```
function updatePersonsWith(id, propName, value) {
  var match = _.find(persons , function(person) { return person.id === id });
  if(match)
      match[propName] = value;
}
```