# How to generate JSON file based on the HTML tag attributes an values

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I would like to save some of HMTL data to JSON file and need help with code which generates JSON using jQuery.
 HTML structure looks like this, but there will be many departments with similar structure including same tags and classes :

```
 <div class="department_one">
      <h1>Name Of Manufacturer</h1>
      <div class="project">
        <div class="project_name">Name of Projects</div>
        <div class="chart">
            <span class="bar red"></span>
            <span class="bar red"></span>
            <span class="bar red"></span>
            <span class="bar red"></span>
            <span class="bar red"></span>
            <span class="bar red"></span>
            <span class="bar blue"></span>
            <span class="bar green"></span>
            <span class="bar green"></span>
            <span class="bar green"></span>
            <span class="bar gray"></span>
        </div>
    </div>    
    </div>
    </div>
```

The data to generated to JSON file:

1. name of manufacturer (from `<h1></h1>`);
2. name of project (from `<div class="project_name">`);
3. span class and sub class attributes (they all have same main class bar, but sub-classes are different and  sub-classes may repeated, as you see there are two span tags with sub-class .red)

I need most advise to how structure JSON if every time there will be different amounts of same sub classes of span tags.

the expected JSON:

```
{
    "holder": [
        {
            "deptName": "main department",
            "project": [
                {
                    "projName": "Proj_1.2",
                    "chartItems": [
                        {
                            "color": "grey",
                            "amount": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "red",
                            "amount": 7
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "blue",
                            "amount": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "green",
                            "amount": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "deptName": "other department",
            "project": [
                {
                    "projName": "Proj_2.2",
                    "chartItems": [
                        {
                            "color": "grey",
                            "amount": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "red",
                            "amount": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "blue",
                            "amount": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "green",
                            "amount": 5
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to implement something?

Comment: Is [**this data**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/YnUr2/1/) enough for your purpose?

Comment: Is your question on how to represent your HTML structure using JSON?

Comment: @MikeBrant not even tried my code, just want someone writes it !!!

Comment: @n1k1ch thanks for suggesting JSON structure

Answer (score 0):

how about this, I guess this what you're looking for

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="holder">
            <div class="department_one">
                <h1>Name Of Manufacturer</h1>
                <div class="project">
                    <div class="project_name">Project 1</div>
                    <div class="chart">
                        <span class="bar red"></span>
                        <span class="bar red"></span>
                        <span class="bar blue"></span>
                        <span class="bar green"></span>
                        <span class="bar gray"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="project">
                    <div class="project_name">Project 2</div>
                    <div class="chart">
                        <span class="bar gray"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="department_one">
                <h1>Name Of Manufacturer 2</h1>
                <div class="project">
                    <div class="project_name">Project 1</div>
                    <div class="chart">
                        <span class="bar red"></span>
                        <span class="bar blue"></span>
                        <span class="bar green"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var json = [];

                var holder = $('#holder');
                var departements = holder.find('> div');
                departements.each(function(idx) {
                    var projects = $(this).find('.project');

                    json[idx] = {};
                    json[idx].manufactor = $(this).find('> h1').text();
                    projects.each(function(project_idx) {
                        var charts = $(this).find('.chart > span');

                        json[idx][project_idx] = {};
                        json[idx][project_idx]['title'] = $(this).find('.project_name').text();
                        json[idx][project_idx]['charts'] = {};
                        charts.each(function() {
                            var title = $(this).attr('class');
                            json[idx][project_idx]['charts'][title] = {'title': title};
                        });
                    });
                });

                console.log(json);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

update: I edit the code, it's working as you want now, but the thing is you should learn to read the code and write your own code, not just asking to the others do that for you, have fun.

update 2:
you may [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688097) and write it by yourself

Comment: thanks for help but its quite different what i am looking for. The holder could have more then one department, each department could have  more then one project and JSON should be structured like this:

Comment: I was trying to write by my self code and had some difficulties and ask for help, thanks again.The structure of generated JSON also should show the number of each color per project. (I have added structure above in my question),appreciate you help again.

Comment: what do you mean, you need I rewrite the code for you again ?

Comment: I just say that I am so thankful but your answer was quite different from I was asking, have a good one